# updating id to max(id)+1

Tags: php, mysql

can someone please help me with the below mysql query:
I want to build a query like:

```
UPDATE users 
SET ref_id = (select max(ref_id)where `role_id`=5) +1 
WHERE user_id =102 
AND `role_id`=5
```

Answer (score 1):

where your FROM clause in subquery???

```
UPDATE users
SET ref_id =
    (select max(ref_id) FROM ???? where role_id=5) + 1
WHERE user_id =102 and role_id=5
```

Comment: I'm wondering why somebody downvoted this

Comment: You don't need a FROM clause when doing an UPDATE request.

Comment: @Pascamel: I don't know. For me this question mustn't downvote

Comment: yes, thanks for the update Alexandre but I need max(id)+1

Comment: thanks, joe, but when I am selecting from the same table inside an update its giving error

Comment: @Pascamel: When I run a query in MySql 5.5 without from it goes in error.

Comment: @srikantamondal: Ok, if you use the same table you must perform in MySql an UPDATE with JOIN. Otherwise use a variable to store your value and then put the value in your update (without subquery)

Comment: thanks for the updates,I got it, the following query works for me       UPDATE
  users JOIN (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(cust_ref_id),0)+1 max_id
                     FROM users) s
SET
  users.cust_ref_id=s.max_id
WHERE
  `user_id`=102

Answer (score 0):

Ok I tried a similar request and I had this MySQL error :

```
1093 - You can't specify target table 'my_table' for update in FROM clause
```

Try using the following request :

```
UPDATE `users`
SET
`ref_id` =
(
 ( SELECT max_id FROM ( SELECT MAX(ref_id) AS max_id FROM users WHERE `role_id`= 5) AS sub_selected_value )
 + 1
)
WHERE `user_id` = 102 AND `role_id` =5
```

Please keep in mind that may not be the most efficient solution if performance matters because it uses temporary tables.